# Querying MySQL database for unique counts of column values

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table structure that is similar to the following:

**Table:** *poll_answers*

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| LONG id | LONG question_id | LONG user_id | TEXT answer      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Users' answers to a poll gets stored into the database as such. `poll_answer` is a string and many answers by different users can be the same.

I would like to query the database to list the number of each unique `poll_answer`.

Example of a poll question with `id` 123 may be:

> What month was xyz born in?

The database might look like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| LONG id | LONG question_id | LONG user_id | TEXT answer      |
----------------------------------------------------------------
| 0       | 123              | 1000         | monday           |
| 1       | 123              | 1001         | tuesday          |
| 2       | 123              | 1003         | monday           |
| 3       | 123              | 1002         | monday           |
| 4       | 123              | 1004         | thursday         |
| 5       | 123              | 1025         | monday           |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I query the database such that I get a list like this:

```
monday => 4
tuesday => 1
thursday => 1
```

The only one I can think of uses `n` number of queries where `n` is the number of different possible `poll_answer`.

```
SELECT UNIQUE answer FROM poll_answers
```

For each of the result,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM poll_answers where answer = {the_answer}
```

Is there a more efficient way?

EDIT:

As a bonus, I would also like to know if efficiency-wise, it would be a good practice to generate and store a hash (MD5) of `answer` in the table and group by the hash instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get answers for ALL questions then try to use this query. It also orders answers for each query by popularity :

```
SELECT question_id,
       answer,
       COUNT(*) as answerCount
   FROM poll_answers
   GROUP BY question_id, answer 
   ORDER BY question_id, answerCount DESC
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c32311/4)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, very good answer. Any chance you saw the additional question at the end?

Comment: @mushroom: I think creating a COMPOSITE INDEX ON (question_id, answer) is enough.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT answer,COUNT(*) as uniqans FROM poll_answers group by answer
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like `group by` is the right direction. Just waiting awhile more to see if someone can answer the additional (closely-related question). Otherwise I will make a new question for that and accept this as answer.

Comment: try http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5